# Spring boot circular dependency issue when using gh-cache

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using spring boot and i want to cache some data here is my entity and repository classes

Places entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLACE_MASTER")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Component
public class PlaceMaster extends BaseEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PLACE_MASTER_ID")
    @JsonView(View.Place.class)
    private long placeMasterId;

    @Column(name = "PLACE_NAME")
    @JsonView(View.Place.class)
    private String placeName;

    @Column(name = "ALT_PLACE_NAME")
    private String alternatePlaceName;

    @Column(name = "PINCODE")
    private String pinCode;

    @Column(name="DISTRICT_NAME")
    private String districtName;

    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATE_MASTER_ID")
    private StateMaster stateMaster;

}
```

state entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STATE_MASTER")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
//@ToString
public class StateMaster extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STATE_MASTER_ID")
    private long stateMasterId;

    @Column(name = "STATE_NAME")
    private String stateName;

    @Column(name = "STATE_CODE")
    private String stateCode;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "stateMaster", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PlaceMaster> placeMaster = new ArrayList<PlaceMaster>();
}


public interface PlaceMasterRepository extends JpaRepository<PlaceMaster, Long> {

   @Override
   @Cacheable("places")
   public List<PlaceMaster> findAll();

}
```

bootstrap application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableAsync
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class myApplication {

   @Autowired
   private PlaceMasterRepository placeMasterRepository;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SpringApplication.run(GoyaanaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

when i run the the spring boot application i am getting the below error. Is it due to biderectional dependency. Please help

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:347)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)

Comment: I wouldn't inject the repository in your main spring boot application. Remember that field injection means that that thing needs to be resolved once the instance is created (= VERY early).

Answer (score 1):

It is generally best to avoid circular dependencies between your bean, e.g. by moving `@EnableCaching`, `@EnableAsync`, `@EnableTransactionManagement` to separate @Configuration class.

In cases where it is not possible, you can get around this by adding a @Lazy annotation on the @Autowired bean. This will create a lazy proxy that will get resolved at runtime. This comes with a caveat - you can't be sure at the start of the application if it is wired up correctly.

```
@Lazy
@Autowired
private PlaceMasterRepository placeMasterRepository;
```

For details see [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html).